# Scala value slf4j is not a member of package org

Tags: scala, import

I'm trying get cross compiling between 2.7.7 and 2.8.0.  The package is included, this works just fine in 2.7.7.  Here's the code:

```
package bizondemand.utils {
package logging  {

import _root_.org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

/**This code copied and pasted from http://johlrogge.wordpress.com/2009/06/27/loggingtools-in-scala/
 *
 */
```

I keep getting the "value slf4j is not a member of package org" error when I compile for 2.8
What's the magic incantation to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+ update
```

in sbt, and voila.